# how to combine textbox values in a linq query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a page in which I have several textboxes in order to search depending the value of the textboxes,If I make the search eith only one value everithing works fine but if I try to combine 2 or more values I only get the result of the last textbox.

Here's my query hope you could help me.

```
var query = from m in SolContext.Menores
                            where ((m.Solicitud.fiIdSolicitud == rdTxtFolio.Value) || (m.Solicitud.fiAnioSolicitud == rdTxtAnioFolio.Value)
                            || (m.Solicitud.CTEdoSolicitud.fcDescEdoSol == status) || (m.Solicitud.fiCircuito == cto) || (m.Solicitud.fiCiudad == cd)
                            || (m.Solicitud.fcCveAdsc == adsc) || (m.Solicitud.fiExpEmpleado == rdTxtExp.Value) || (m.Solicitud.fcNomEmpleado == rdTxtNom.Text)
                            || (m.Solicitud.fcPatEmpleado == rdTxtAPat.Text) || (m.Solicitud.fcMatEmpleado == rdTxtAMat.Text) || (m.fcPatMenor == rdTxtAPatMenor.Text)
                            || (m.fcMatMenor == rdTxtAmatMenor.Text) || (m.fcNomMenor == rdTxtNomMenor.Text) || (m.fiSexoMenor == sexo) || (m.fiAnosMenor == rdTxtAniosMenor.Value) || (m.fiMesesMenor == rdTxtMesMenor.Value))
                            select m;
                rgSolic.DataSource = query;
                rgSolic.Rebind();
```

Comment: You have't selected an answer to any of your previous questions...

Comment: No one wants to help if you don't accept answers (click the arrow icon next to the answer that best works to accept it as the answer). It's how people get recognized and helps the integrety of the site.

Comment: Ok I already did it now Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the result of the first textbox is included in the result of the second one.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using or. The first textbox that matches your value will end your search. If you want to check if it matches all your values, use and.

If that doesn't solve it, we'll need more info.